# Why can I send AWS S3 bucket events to only one AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a S3 bucket, to store objects.

On the object creation event, I wish to send a specific category of objects to two lambdas, in parallel:

1. `my_email_lambda`
2. `my_logging_lambda`

I set the rule as follows:

```
Rule 1:
  Prefix: /my/folder
  Suffix:
  Send to: lambda
  Lambda: my_email_lambda

Rule 2:
  Prefix: /my/folder
  Suffix:
  Send to: lambda
  Lambda: my_logging_lambda
```

When I try to do this, I get an error:

> Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes
>   in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.

Why is this ambiguous? I want to send the events to two separate lambdas. If this were a `move` operation, then we could consider this setup to be ambiguous. This is an event notification operation, though. This is not ambiguous. If the operation is unsupported, the error message should state this instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported. And agree that the error message is not good.

The reason, I think is just that they want to promote another practice: [Fanout S3 Event Notifications to Multiple Endpoints | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/fanout-s3-event-notifications-to-multiple-endpoints/)